Correlation coefficients in the limit
I was wondering the following:
Let $\rho_{A B}$ be the correlation coefficients between variables $A$ and $B$. Let's suppose we gradually change the data generating process of A, holding everything else constant, such that $\rho_{A B}$ goes to one.
Does this necessarily imply that as $\rho_{A B}$ goes to one, for any arbitrary third variable variable $C$, $\rho_{A C}$ approaches $\rho_{B C}$ as we change $A's$ data generating process in the way described?
To put it into math, do we have that:
$\lim _{\rho_{A B} \rightarrow 1} \rho_{A C}=\rho_{B C}$
Edit:
If it was not true, what is a simple example of such a data-generating process where $\rho_{A C}$ does not approach $\rho_{B C}$ in the limit? (Assuming the limit exists)

The answer depends on how you change the variables, but without being more specific, there's nothing you can say: $\rho_{AC}$ could converge to any value, if it converges at all (which is not guaranteed).  That's why in your earlier deleted version of this question I encouraged you to explain how these variables are changing.  If you do care to clarify your question, please do not delete it: just edit it.

Thanks for your answer! Can you give me a simple example where $\rho_{A C}$ does not approach $\rho_{B C}$ in the limit? I can't come up with any...

I responded too hastily and apologize (with an upvote), because your assertion is correct.  Intuitively, $\rho$ is a metric on the space of square-integrable variables modulo their lengths and the result follows from that.

Much appreciated!
